# How to check multiple objects in another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I want to check whether one of object is exist in another array.

My object is:

```
class obj: NSObject {
    var obj_id: Int?
    var status: Int?
}
```

> NOTE : I want to compare by `obj_id`.

For example, an array of [obj1, obj2 ,obj3], I want to check if obj2 or obj3 are in the array [obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5].

Comment: How about Filter method? `code`
let find = otherArray.filter { itemInOtherAray.obj_id == object.obj_id }.first 
if (find != nil) { 
//do something
} `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains(where:)`.

Unclear what the goal was supposed to be, so here's an example that tests whether *any* element of the first array is an element of the second array (using the `obj_id` property):

```
class Obj: NSObject {
    var obj_id: Int?
    init(obj_id:Int?) {
        self.obj_id = obj_id
    }
}
let arr1 = [Obj(obj_id: 1)],Obj(obj_id: 2),Obj(obj_id: 3)]
let arr2 = [Obj(obj_id: 2),Obj(obj_id: 3),Obj(obj_id: 4),Obj(obj_id: 5)]

var result = false
for ob in arr1 {
    if arr2.contains(where: {$0.obj_id == ob.obj_id}) { // <--
        result = true
        break
    }
}
result // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, it will convert the 2 arrays into sets and check for intersection.

```
class obj: NSObject {

    var obj_id: Int?
    var status: Int?

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        return self.obj_id == (object as? obj)?.obj_id
    }
}

if !Set(firstArray).intersection(Set(secondArray)).isEmpty {
    // both arrays have something in common
}
```